# Finding True and False values with df.query

Tags: python, pandas

I have concatenated two dataframes with consistent columns. One of the column is entitled `isForecast` where the top dataframe has a value of False, and for the dataframe it is True (I am adding a forecast to actuals data). From this point I put the data through a sklearn regression which is working but when I try to unpack the forecast I get an error.

```
allData = pd.concat([actuals, forecast])
allData = adjustment(allData,periodLength) #### this is a seperate function but the 'isForecast'column remains consistent.

forecastOutput = allData.query('isForecast').copy() ## error here
```

The error I am getting doesn't make sense. My index is a column entitled 'datetime' and is not  being referenced.

> None of [Index([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,\n       ...\n        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],\n      dtype='object', name='datetime', length=91968)] are in the [index]

Any suggestions or comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working your solution, alternative is compare by `True`:

```
allData = pd.DataFrame({'isForecast':[True, False, True]})

forecastOutput = allData.query('isForecast').copy()
print(forecastOutput)
   isForecast
0        True
2        True
```

---

```
forecastOutput = allData.query('isForecast == True').copy()
print(forecastOutput)
   isForecast
0        True
2        True
```

Or boolean indexing:

```
forecastOutput = allData[allData['isForecast']]
print(forecastOutput)
   isForecast
0        True
2        True
```

If values are not boolean:

```
allData = pd.DataFrame({'isForecast':['True', 'False', 'True']})

forecastOutput = allData.query('isForecast == "True"').copy()
print(forecastOutput)
  isForecast
0       True
2       True
```

Comment: thank Jezrael - the last one appeared to solve my problem. I have a suspicion I have some dodgey data which I will have to rectify.Thankyou